# R Unit Test using devtools::test() executes source code instead of test cases

Tags: r, unit-testing, devtools, testthat

I'm new to R and I'm having some trouble to get the testthat unit test package work via devtools::test().

I've setup a package and created a test case under the .\tests\testthat folder. My R source code files are located at .\R.

When I run:

```
testthat::test_dir("./tests/testthat/")
```

The test ran successfully.

However when I tried to run the test via

```
devtools::test()
```

Instead of running the test cases, it tried to run my source code files located under .\R.

How can I get devtools::test() to just run my test cases?

Thank you for your help.

BTW, there is little documentation about how to setup and use testthat which is very frustrating as a new R user.

Answer (score 1):

`test()` (re)loads your package before running your tests. That's why you see your package source code being executed.

Comment: As my source R files are not just function libraries and some of the files contain code will be run directly when sourced. Is there a way to stop devtools::test() from sourcing the files?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense

Comment: sorry if my comment has confused you. I'm still new to R. What I'm trying to say is in some of my R source files, when they are sourced, it will trigger some tasks to be run directly. I don't want this to happen when I call devtools::test(). I just want devtools::test() to run my test cases under testthat.

Comment: hi @Allen, In your case I think you could put those R scripts somewhere else. Only put functions in `./R` directory.